# JavaScript - Weird usage of Date.getDate() for to get the days-count of a month. How does that work?

Tags: javascript, date

I've seen that code-technique, trick, hack (how you wanna call it) on CodeReview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142706/take-a-specified-weekday-and-check-if-it-falls-on-the-remaining-days-of-the-cur

In the 6th line the `getDate()` method is used for to get the count of days of a month. Month specified as the previous parameter.

I've played around with these technique and it seems to work:

```js
var d = new Date();
    
var sep = new Date(d.getYear(), (d.getMonth() + 1), 0).getDate();
var oct = new Date(d.getYear(), (d.getMonth() + 2), 0).getDate();
var nov = new Date(d.getYear(), (d.getMonth() + 3), 0).getDate();
var dec = new Date(d.getYear(), (d.getMonth() + 4), 0).getDate();
var jan = new Date(d.getYear(), (d.getMonth() + 5), 0).getDate();

console.log(d.toLocaleString('en-US', { month: 'long' }));
console.log('%s %s %s %s %s', sep, oct, nov, dec, jan);
```

**But how is it possible that it works?**

I would expect the Date-constructor to accept only valid integers.

One can give it whatever integer one likes. It doesn't throw an exception. BUT: The returned values are scrap.

```js
var d = new Date();
    
var nov = new Date(d.getYear(), (d.getMonth() + 3), 31).getDate(); // November has 30 days.
console.log('%s', nov); // => 31

var nov = new Date(d.getYear(), (d.getMonth() + 3), -21).getDate(); // November has 30 days.
console.log('%s', nov); // 9 

var nov = new Date(d.getYear(), (d.getMonth() + 3), 301).getDate(); // November has 30 days.
console.log('%s', nov); // 27
```

**Can anyone with some insights explain what goes on there?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a property of the `Date` class, as documented on MDN:

> Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, if values are greater than their logical range (e.g. 13 is provided as the month value or 70 for the minute value), the adjacent value will be adjusted. E.g. new Date(2013, 13, 1) is equivalent to new Date(2014, 1, 1), both create a date for 2014-02-01 (note that the month is 0-based). Similarly for other values: new Date(2013, 2, 1, 0, 70) is equivalent to new Date(2013, 2, 1, 1, 10) which both create a date for 2013-03-01T01:10:00.

They talk about values greater than their logical range, but the same logic applies for values lower than their range.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Ah, okay. I causes some kind of "wrap-around". Right?

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date();
```

var nov = new Date(d.getYear(), (d.getMonth() + 3), 31).getDate(); // November has 30 days.
console.log('%s', nov); // => 31   Thu Dec 31  2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

var nov = new Date(d.getYear(), (d.getMonth() + 3), -21).getDate(); // November has 30 days.
console.log('%s', nov); // 9  Mon Nov 09  2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

var nov = new Date(d.getYear(), (d.getMonth() + 3), 301).getDate(); // November has 30 days.
console.log('%s', nov); // 27  Mon Sep 27  2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)